# Is there a verb that means 'to stare down' or 'to stare in order to intimidate'?

Tags: single-word-requests

Boxers often stare each other in the eyes before a match. Animals will often do the same in an attempt to avoid a physical conflict. People often use starring in order to intimidate others. I suspect there's a word for it. Does anyone know whether there is one?

Thank you.

-Hal

Comment: **Glares** at Hal.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger I thought a glare was an angry glance. I checked the definition; I was wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verbs "glare" and "glower" both refer to intense, menacing stares.

"scowl" is similar, but includes scrunching up your forehead ("furrowed brow")

Also there is the phrase "give [someone] the evil eye", which has a slight connotation of witchcraft, like putting a "hex" (bad luck) on your opponent.

also (old-fashioned, I think): 
(to) "look daggers"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps *[eyeball](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/eyeball)*

> Look or stare at closely:
>   *we eyeballed one another*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

There is also *[stink eye](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=stink%20eye)*

> a surfer term meaning a glare or lingering dirty look
>   *when that dude stole my wave I gave him 
>   total stink eye*

*Urban Dictionary* (and its use has gone way beyond surfers)

In both of these cases, these terms may be used for one-sided staring as well.